# mysql single-session, multiple concurrent create temp table, isolation REPEATABLE-READ

Tags: mysql, concurrency, isolation-level

In a single session I'd like to have two different routines that each creates their own temp tables (and insert values into them) inside of their own transactions. The db's tx_isolation is REPEATABLE-READ. Under what circumstances would the routines be able to make progress concurrently -  if the tables had the same name would they be forced into serial order? If the temp table names are different would they not need transactions in the first place.

Comment: what is your definition of `In a single session` ?

Comment: I didn't realize there were different ways to interpret that. Perhaps of you listed some options, I could be more helpful.

Comment: referring to session transaction isolation levels of mysql